# How to Compare today's date and date stored in table

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I have a table called TblLogin with 3 columns and only one record:

```
LoginID  LoginName  firstlogindate
-----------     ------------------   ---------------------
   1       test       10-Jan-17
```

Now i want to display a message If today's date is greater than the [date stored in column firstlogindate + 7 days].

I used the `DATEADD` function of MS Access in the following code to add 7 days on the date recorded in the column firstlogindate.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim DateAddition As String
DateAddition = "SELECT DateAdd('d',7,[FirstLoginDate]) " & _
        "FROM TblLogin " & _
        "where TblLogin.[LoginName] ='test';"
End Sub
```

But i have no clue as to how to perform the checking to find out wether today's date is greater than `[firstlogindate+7days]`.

Please Can someone help me out? 
Or is there a better way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    If DateDiff("d", DLookup("[FirstLoginDate]", "TblLogin", "[LoginName] ='test'"), Date) > 7 Then
        MsgBox "You are late.", vbInformation + vbOkOnly, "Loging Date"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gustav. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Use **conditional formatting** on a form to do this. I had the same kind of task to do and this is the way I solved it.

1. Create a datasheet/tabular form from your table.
2. Go in Design View of your form
3. Select your field (here *firstlogindate*)
4. Click conditional formatting
5. Add a new rule using DateDiff("d",[firstlogindate],Date()) and apply the formatting you want.

This method allows you to spot the records with more than 7 days difference by **highlighting** them, it won't display a MsgBox though.

Comment: Thanks Seb, but your suggestion isn't actually going to work for me. Actually I want to deliver a demo application, so I want to add an expiration date on the only login account stored in TblLogin. The logic I want to used is the following : we auto record the first login date in the TblLogin the first time we login into the db application (done). The loginName used has a maximum of 7 days to use the db application, after that 7 days grace period the system should display a warning message and exit access when we try to use that login Name to access the db application.

Comment: Ok I see, well in this case you could try using `DoCmd.GotoRecord` or `DoCmd.FindRecord` to get its value and then compare it. OR if make it a form, you can use `DLookup` to return the value (really easy since there is only one record) and then again. I hope this will solve your problem